# React Table toggleRowExpanded not working

Tags: reactjs, react-table

We are using react-table and we would like to `collapse/expand` the next available row in the `react-table`. For this, we are using react-table `toggleRowExpanded` passing row-id as the first param. This function isn't working as expected.

```
toggleRowExpanded([id], true);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add a [mre]!

Comment: @0stone0 Thank You for showing interest. Please let me know if anymore information is needed. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cannon-6x31o

Answer (score 1):

As from react-table documentation, **toggleRowExpanded** is a function to toggle whether 'a' row is expanded or not. toggleRowExpanded expects a **single rowId** rather than an array of ids and an optional **isExpanded** boolean value which is the status of that single row.

In the example codesandbox shared, 2 changes to note :

1. rowId is not the id from the data - but the id of the row in the table - which will be the index in this case
2. toggleRowExpanded function is to be called separately for each row.

For the example to work,

```
   data.forEach((val, index) => {
          toggleRowExpanded(index, isEven ? index%2 === 0 : false);
        })
```

Comment: Any hints on making id from the data as id of the row. Thank You for the comment.

Comment: Just use the `rows` variable from `useTable` instead of the `data` variable.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thank You for the comment. Instead of using `index`, is it possible to use `val.id` to identify the expanded `row`?